# Primes that divide $2^{\frac{p-1}2}+1$

Tags: number-theory

$p$ is a prime and $p\equiv 3,5 \pmod8$. Prove that $p\ | \ 2^{\frac{p-1}2} +1$.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're aiming to show then that  $2^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv -1 \bmod p$

This is equivalent to saying that $2$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod p$, since if there were some $b$ such that $b^2 \equiv 2 \bmod p$ then since $b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ then also $2^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 1 \bmod p$

So, if allowed, you could use the [Legendre symbol rules of quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol) to complete the proof. Or if not, your result would effectively prove that part of the rules.